# give delay in showing the controls

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I would like to add the button controls in a timely manner.
That means, after the shell opened, it should start placing the buttons one by one
in a 1 second delay. I wrote the program,however it does not work. all the buttons
are visible only after all the controls are placed. Some kind of refresh issue I guess.
Following is my code.

```java
public class DelayAddingComponentsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(200, 200);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
        addAutomatically(shell);
        // removeAutomatically(shell);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void addAutomatically(final Shell shell) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
            button.setText("Button" + i);
            button.setVisible(false);

        }

        shell.getDisplay().timerExec(0, new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
                        button.setText("Button" + i);
                        button.setVisible(true);
                        shell.pack();
                        shell.layout(true);
                        shell.redraw();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        });
    }
    public static void removeAutomatically(final Shell shell) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
            button.setText("Button" + i);
            shell.layout(true);
        }
        shell.getDisplay().timerExec(0, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Control[] controls = shell.getChildren();
                for (Control control : controls) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        control.dispose();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Runnable` given to `timerExec` runs in the UI thread. So the `Thread.sleep` calls you are making are blocking the UI thread - it is vital that you never block this thread. **Never** call `Thread.sleep` in the UI thread.

You must do each step using a separate `timeExec` call and use the delay parameter of the `timerExec` call to specify how long to wait.

So

```java
shell.getDisplay().timerExec(500, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
     // TODO code for the first button only

     // Schedule next update
     shell.getDisplay().timerExec(500, .... code for second button);
    }
  });
```

Runs the Runnable after 500 millseconds, the Runnable should just do the first step and then call `timerExec` again to schedule the next step.